# How could i apply separate styles for odd and even div tags

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on asp.net mvc 4 with razor view. I am trying to display the odd div tags with style `float:left` and even div tags with style `float:right`. Here my div tags are like,

```
    <div id="content" style="padding-top:80px;">
    @foreach (var item in (List<System.Data.DataRow>)ViewBag.List)
    {
        <a href="@string.Format("Products?id={0}",item[0])">
        <div class="img">

            <table align="center" cellspacing="12">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <b>@item[1]</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center; color: DodgerBlue; font-size: xx-large; border-top: 1px solid Gray;
                        border-bottom: 1px solid gray; font-weight: bolder;">
                        $@item[2]
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        @item[3]
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        No Trail period
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <div class="divOuter" style="float:left;margin:4px;width:100%;height:40px;text-align:left">
                 @foreach (var i in ProductOption.ProductOptions(Convert.ToInt32(item[0])))
                 {
                     <div class="divInner" style="display:inline;width:50%;"><input type="checkbox" value="@i[0]" checked="checked" /><span style="line-height:20px;font-weight:bold;">@i[0]</span></div>
                 }
                 </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div></a>
    }
</div>
```

I have uses jquery like,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
           $("div.divOuter div.divInner:odd").css("float","left");
           $("div.divOuter div.divInner:even").css("float", "right");
       });
```

How could i apply float:left for odd div tags and float:right for even div tags. please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the `id` of the inner divs, set their `class` to `divInner`.  Then change your selectors to look like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $("div.divOuter .divInner:odd").css("float","left");
       $("div.divOuter .divInner:even").css("float", "right");
   });
```

IDs are supposed to be unique within in an HTML document.

Comment: Note that `:even` and `:odd` use 0-based indexing, so it seems backwards.  I've swapped the styles so it matches what you're probably expecting.

Comment: I have tried in all ways that you mentiones but i didnt get.actually i have both divOuter and divInner in table again the table.

Comment: Sorry, cannot parse your sentence.  Compare the HTML & CSS in my jsfiddle and see what the difference is.  Maybe you should just post your entire output HTML instead of your Razor code, since this is unrelated to Razor and since you may have other markup that's interfering.

Comment: I have also test my code in jfiddler it is working as i desired. but here i am generating div tags dynamically using foreach loop i think thats why any css properties were added to div tags.

Comment: They are being generated server-side, so there should be no difference in the how the JavaScript affects the content whether it's dynamic or static.  Post your jsfiddle and your Razor code and we can see why you're seeing a difference.

Comment: You now are using a `class` of `divInner` but are using a selector for an `id` of `divInner`.  Change your `div#divInner` selectors to `div.divInner`.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a big part - there cannot be multiple ids with the same name. You can use a class and then use a selector and it will work.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/FMp35/3/